# animated directional bar/ power meter gauge android

Tags: java, android

I at a loss of where to begin with this.
I am try to draw a horizontal bar that has a slider moving left to right
(similar to what is seen in basketball shootout games for aiming the ball).
I would like to be able to control the speed it moves left to right and then stop it
on touch or something of that nature.

same idea with a vertical bar increasing and decreasing like a strength meter.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pre-defined component to do this, but you can do this using a `ProgressBar` or `SeekBar`:

1. Create your ProgressBar, either horizonal or vertical.
2. Create a Runnable that changes the ProgressBar value: increment it until it hits the max and then sets it to zero and start over. You can pick the amount that it increments each time it runs based on the desired resolution.
3. Use `postDelayed` to schedule the Runnable on the ui thread, and every time the Runnable updates the values it will reschedule itself based on the interval you choose, which should control the speed.
4. When someone taps the ProgressBar set a flag that stops the Runnable from updating the value.

You can then use the progress bar value as the final number.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html for the ProgressBar details and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29 for the use of `postDelayed`.

Comment: Excellent! I will read the links and try that out. Thank You!!